# sort array on date

Tags: arrays, uitableview, sorting

I have populated a TableView with an Array that consists of strings that are dates.

For example: 22-06-2014 (dd-mm-yyyy).

Has anyone got an idea how I can sort the array so that the most recent date will come on top?

Comment: Convert the date into an `NSDate` using a `NSDateFormatter`. Sort the dates. Convert it back to a string.

Comment: Xcode isn't a programming language.  It's an IDE, and you can write code in numerous different languages with Xcode.  You mention a tableview, so perhaps we can assume you're writing in Objective-C or Swift... but even still, it's a coinflip as to which one.

Comment: @dasdom No need to convert twice.  See my answer.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming Objective-C, first create a `NSDateFormatter` so we can turn these into dates for accurate comparison:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
```

Now, sort them as dates:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayOfDateStrings sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    return [[df dateFromString:a] compare:[df dateFromString:b]];
}];
```

Now `sortedArray` is a sorted array of the original strings.